# MS Access 2007: embedding tiff images in forms

Tags: image, forms, ms-access, vba, tiff

my problem seems simple: I need to display an tiff image in a form, with the path of the image chosen from the combobox value. I had tried to use almost all the default controls + some activex objects (i.e. web browser control), but without any luck.

My question is: what is the preferred, least obtrusive way to accomplish this task?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get ms-access to display images from external files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112/is-there-a-way-to-get-ms-access-to-display-images-from-external-files)

Comment: Well, except for the fact thay TIFF is not a format that the Access image control can display. The suggestion to use an embedded web browser control doesn't work, either, because neither of the web browser controls I know of that work in Access (IE and Gecko) support display of TIFFs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that there's any way to display a TIFF directly in Access unless you can find a 3rd-party ActiveX control to do it (the AccessImagine control cited in the article @CodeSlave refers to in a comment above doesn't support TIFF).

I don't think TIFF is not a very good format for this kind of thing, actually. It might be that you would just need to open the TIFFs in an external image viewer. If you do this with the function version of Shell(), you should then be able to kill the process after you're done with it.

I don't see any good solution here.