# MS Access - Select and Store Files externally out of database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a contract database that

- I want to let users upload files from a Windows Explorer window to each individual contract record
- then have it stored on a centralized shared drive.

So when you would go between records it would show the individual files per each record.

Is this possible and is there a basic logic to this as I've never done something like this.

Thank you in advance.

I'm not sure if this has been answered and if it is I would appreciate the forward of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with a single form but not with a continuous form.

- You'll want to use [Application.FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196794(v=office.15).aspx) to prompt the user for a file and I prefer to use [FileSystemObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba) to manipulate files (e.g. copy or move). You can prompt the user to "upload" a file when they click a button you provide.
- Either come up with a convention or store the path to the file in the shared in your record.
- How you display the file is up to you. Here are some options:

  1. Provide an View button or link that will call [Application.FollowHyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822080(v=office.15).aspx), passing in the path to the file.
  2. [Display an image in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112/is-there-a-way-to-get-ms-access-to-display-images-from-external-files)
  3. [Display certain files like a Word document in the form](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/display-word-document-access-form-t1123142.html)

Those links should get you everything you need but let me know if I missed something. Also, I'm not certain that options 2 and 3 will work in Access 2010. I've used both techniques but it has been a long time.