# Graphing in Microsoft Access using ggplot2 package

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am working with a tool written in Microsoft Access and my job is to replace some of the graphs/charts in the tool with graphs created in ggplot2 in R.
I can create the graphs in R and copy paste it to the tool but the problem is the tool is used by people who are not familiar with R language so I need to make an automation connecting R and Microsoft Access. Has anyone did this before? Thanks for your help.
Breeze

Comment: This question as is too broad to help as you provide no actual, specific coding/data example. *I am working with a tool written in Microsoft Access*...what is this tool? Please edit with specificity.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63 may be a gd start to at least calling R and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112/is-there-a-way-to-get-ms-access-to-display-images-from-external-files lets you display images from external files.

Comment: I think you need some more detail here as well.  It sounds like you want to have people dynamically pass data from Microsoft access to an r studio server then pass back an image to display in Microsoft access?  My first response is don't do this. However if you must look at the plumber package: https://www.rplumber.io/

Comment: @Parfait what the tool does is not really the focus of my question. All I want to do is where the tool produces a graph/pie chart/plot I replace it with the similar R visual using ggplot2. as if the two softwares talk to each other when there is a visual involved. I have seen some VBA codes that might connect the two softwares but I am not a VBA programmer.

Comment: @IanWesley What you described is exactly what I want to do.  I should start playing with your recommended package to see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for your suggestions. The first link seems more like the solution for my case.